# Fail uploading any sketch to ATtiny85 USB

Tags: attiny

I have a Digistump's ATtiny85 (probably a clone ), which fails uploading any sketch, saying: `Warning: device with unknown new version of Micronucleus detected. This tool doesn't know how to upload to this new device. Updates may be available.` I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and Arduino IDE 1.8.13.

I used these guides:

1. [Digistump's troubleshooting for linux](https://digistump.com/wiki/digispark/tutorials/linuxtroubleshooting)
2. [Kovo's blog](https://kovo-blog.blogspot.com/2019/01/how-to-upgrade-bootloader-on-digistump.html)

After using these guides, finally I stop getting this error, but when trying to upload the firmware ( last line at Kovo's ), I get this error:

```
`guy@desktop:~/tmp/micronucleus/upgrade$ ~/.arduino15/packages/digistump/tools/micronucleus/2.0a4/launcher -cdigispark  --timeout 60 -Uflash:w:~/tmp/micronucleus/upgrade/t85_default.hex:i
Running Digispark Uploader...
Plug in device now... (will timeout in 60 seconds)
> Please plug in the device (will time out in 60 seconds) ... 
> Device is found!
connecting: 16% complete
connecting: 22% complete
connecting: 28% complete
connecting: 33% complete
> Device has firmware version 2.4
> Device signature: 0x1e930b 
> Available space for user applications: 6522 bytes
> Suggested sleep time between sending pages: 7ms
> Whole page count: 102  page size: 64
> Erase function sleep duration: 714ms
parsing: 50% complete
> Program file is 1594 bytes too big for the bootloader!
```

Did someone encounter this ?

Comment: I'd probably start here: https://github.com/micronucleus/micronucleus/issues/148

Answer (score -1):

[from Daves Comment](https://github.com/micronucleus/micronucleus/issues/148)

need to download `upgrade-t85.hex` (which is not `t85_default.hex`) from [link](https://github.com/micronucleus/micronucleus/files/2837520/upgrade-t85_default.zip)